# The Polyhedron of Euler theorem about loop definition

Tags: general-topology

The book of Armstrong Basic Topology states the Euler theorem.

[image]

I can almost follow the proof from the book.

I know the theorem can apply like this figure. But, how about the red loop?

Does this red loop separates P into two pieces?
[image]

The proof is almost same with the [link](https://www.iitg.ac.in/clubs/rsf_math/events/resources/RSF-LS2-Pure.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have two pieces, 1 the red triangle, 2 the rest, when you would make it from paper there would not be any doubt.